# Multiple ports to a single Client in Socket Programming

Tags: c#

Can we assign multiple ports to a single client, i.e.
one port for sending data and another port is for receiving data for the same Client?
Is it possible using socket communication?

If possible how can we implement in C# socket programming?

Comment: @MitchWheat - just don't bother commenting next time, flagged.. OP, Yes, it's possible, and indeed if you connect to port 80 on a server, the server sends back to a different port on the client.  That's a part of TCP already.  What are you looking to achieve - you can already send/receive on the same port?

Comment: FTP does this.  One connection for control communication, and another for data communication.  Does it make sense?...just depends on your architecture!  Bear in mind, though, that each port would need its own TcpClient/TcpListener.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, a single `TcpClient` listens on a single local port, but remember it's bi-directional so there's usually no need to separate communication channels like this.

If you want to provide another channel to receive on then you can create a `TcpListener` bound to whatever IP/port you want to receive on and have the client send the listener binding details to the other side so they know what to connect to.

Also be aware that setting up local listening endpoints may run into problems around NAT, firewalls and port forwarding.